# How to redirect the page and disable other router in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to direct the first time user from login page to setting page to do some config works.(if it is existing user they will go to home page as usual), and if they are first time user, I also need to disable all other link in the page unless they finish those setting. Here is my attempt to do it, but it doesn't work for some reasons, would you please point out for me? Thanks a lot.

```
 angular.module('ecom').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        var expenseModalInstance;
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
        }).state('reports', {
            url: '/reports',
            templateUrl: 'submitter/reports/report-list.html'
        }).state('ebin', {
            url: '/ebin',
            templateUrl: 'submitter/ebin/ebin-expense-list.html'
        })..state('accountsetting', {
            url: '/account',
            templateUrl: 'settings/settings.html'
        }).state('accountsetting.security', {
            url: '/security',
            templateUrl: 'settings/security/security.html',
            resolve:{
                userInfor: ['$stateParams', 'userinfoservice', function($stateParams, userinfoservice){
                   var isFirstTime;
                            if ($stateParams.rid) {
                                userinfoservice.getUserinfo($stateParams.rid).then(function(data) {
                                    isFirstTime = data.isFirstTimeLogin;
                                });
                            }
                     return isFirstTime;
                    }]
            }
       }).run(['$state','$rootScope', function($state,$rootScope) {
    // var isFirstTimeUser = false;
    //     userinforservice.getUserInformation().then(function(data){
    //            isFirstTimeUser = data.isFirstTimeUser; 
    //            $rootScope.$broadcast('session:resolved', isFirstTimeUser);
    //     });
   var isFirstTimeUser = true;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(isFirstTimeUser){
            $state.go('accountsetting');
        }else{
            $state.go('home');
        }
    });
}]);
```

As you can see, if it is new user I will  take them to accountsetting.security, I have a resolve to call server to get this user information, if it isFirstTime return true, I will do something in setting security controller, and also I need to disable all other routers such as reports,ebin etc. Is it a way to do it? or any good idea to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cancel the navigation event in order to decide if a user can access a page or not. This is a little tricky as most of the times this action needs to be performed asynchronously. I propose you one way to accomplish it.

In the run block of your app, add a `$stateChangeStart` event handler, where you will perform the needed request:

```
module.run((function($rootScope, $urlRouter, $state, userinfoservice){
  var isResolved = false;

  performSomeAsyncRequest()
  .then(function(data) {
    var isFirstTime = data.isFirstTimeLogin;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('session:resolved', isFirstTime);
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (!isResolved && toState.name !== 'accountsetting.security') {
      event.preventDefault(); // stop the navigation

      var resolveListener = $rootScope.$on('session:resolved', function(event, isFirstTime){
        isResolved = true;
        resolveListener() // cancel event listener

        if (isFirstTime) {
          $state.go('accountsetting.security'); //redirect
        } else {
          $urlRouter.sync(); //resume previous navigation
        }
      });
    }

  });

});
```

Now this probably is not exactly fixing your use case, I would need more code in order to do that, but it should give you an idea on how to stop a navigation and resume it after some async action.

Comment: Hey Thanks dude!  It real gave me a idea, let me give a try!

Comment: It gave me a error like this in console: angular.js:11706RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. I just updated the code,

Comment: Yes, of course it will give you that error because you created an infinite loop. `$state.go` will trigger a `$stateChangeStart` event every time, so you are executing the same listener over and over again. You should only redirect to 'accountsetting.security' if isFirstTime and not nextState.name is 'accountsetting.security'.